# Using RAISERROR to indicate ACCESS DENIED error

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, raiserror

I have a sproc that verifies whether the caller is authorized to call this sproc with given params. In case when the caller is not authorized, I want to `RAISERROR` with ACCESS DENIED error number. Now, it cannot be error number 10011 (ACCESS DENIED in sys.messages), because the error number has to be greater than 50000. I don't want to add the same messages (english and localized texts as well) using `sp_addmessage` sproc just to recreate the same ACCESS DENIED error. What's the right way to do this?

**EDIT:** since required SQL code was supposed to be compatible with SQL Azure,  I ended up calling `RAISERROR` with no error number and checking for default 50,000 error code in code behind (in SQL Azure there is currently no support for `sp_addmessage` and `sys.messages`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this as what you want to raise is not an `Access denied` error, but rather an `Access denied with these parameters` error. 
Hence you need to create a custom error and raise that.

If you want the "real" access denied error it is a matter of revoking exec rights on the procedure.

Answer (score 2):

create a table `AccessDeniedTable` that the current DB user will never have access to.  when you hit your logical `ACCESS DENIED` condition issue a `SELECT @x=COUNT(*) FROM AccessDeniedTable` which should throw the actual error you are after.

```
IF @Accesslevel<5 ---your condition here
BEGIN
    SELECT @x=COUNT(*) FROM AccessDeniedTable --throw standard ACCESS DENIED error
    RAISERROR('FATAL ERROR',16,1) --just in case actual error is not thrown
    RETURN 999999 --just in case
END
```

Comment: this will produce the following confusing red herring error message: "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'AccessDeniedTable', database 'FOO', schema 'dbo'." not desirable at all.

Comment: @kateroh, use this idea but change the `select ...` to whatever will cause your intended system message.